# cant insert the difference of this into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is my insert section the $total_minutes and $total_hour cant be inserted in the table

```
$year = $_POST['year'];  
$month = $_POST['month'];  
$day = $_POST['day'];  
$hour = $_POST['hour'];  
$min = $_POST['min'];  
$sec = $_POST['sec'];  
$year1 = $_POST['year1'];  
$month1 = $_POST['month1'];  
$day1 = $_POST['day1'];  
$hour1 = $_POST['hour1'];  
$min1 = $_POST['min1'];  
$sec1 = $_POST['sec1'];  
$time_in = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$hour.'-'.$min.'-'.$sec;  
$time_out = $year1.'-'.$month1.'-'.$day1.' '.$hour1.'-'.$min1.'-'.$sec1;
$total_minutes = $total_min;
$total_hour = $total_hr;

$sql = "INSERT INTO time (year, month, day, hour, min, sec, year1, month1, day1, hour1, min1, sec1, time_in, time_out, total_minutes, total_hour)
    VALUES
    ('$year','$month','$day','$hour','$min','$sec','$year1','$month1','$day1','$hour1','$min1','$sec1','$time_in','$time_out', '$total_minutes', '$total_hour')";
```

how can i add this in my table?

---

> minutes

```
    $datetime1 = strtotime($row['time_in']); //year-month-day hr:min:sec timein  
$datetime2 = strtotime($row['time_out']); //year-month-day hr:min:sec timeout  
$interval = abs($datetime2 - $datetime1);  
$total_min = round($interval / 60);  
$total_minutes = $total_min;
```

> hour

```
function convertToHoursMins($total_minutes, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
    if ($total_minutes < 1) {
        return;
    }
    $hours = floor($total_minutes / 60);
    $wmin = ($total_minutes % 60);
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $wmin);
}
$total_hr = convertToHoursMins($total_minutes, '%02d hours %02d minutes');
$total_hour = $total_hr;
```

im new and i wanted a simple answer

Comment: Whats the value of `time_in` and `time_out`? Are you getting any error

Comment: what error r u getting?

Comment: @Uchiha sorry just change the $datetime1 = strtotime($time_in) and $datetime2 = strtotime($time_out)

Comment: i like to insert the $time_minutes and $time_hour to database @devpro

Comment: @ReyJoelLauronMatugas but what value those variables are carrying

Comment: @Uchiha it will inserted through forms sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your datetime1 and datetime2 in this format first :

```
datetime1 =   2012-01-01   12:00:00;
datetime2 =   2012-01-02   13:00:00;
```

Then in my sql insert query directly insert value from following functions :

TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, datetime2, datetime1) // For Hours Calculation
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,datetime2, datetime1) // For Minutes Calculation

Hope this may help you :)

Comment: so how can i put the result of TIMESTAMPDIFF into $total_minutes or $total_hour

Comment: Don't take this value in any variable. Dircectly use this function inplace of $total_minutes and $total_hour veriable in insert query like this : 

$sql = "INSERT INTO time (year, month, day, hour, min, sec, year1, month1, day1, hour1, min1, sec1, time_in, time_out, total_minutes, total_hour)
    VALUES
    ('$year','$month','$day','$hour','$min','$sec','$year1','$month1','$day1','$hour1','$min1','$sec1','$time_in','$time_out',TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, $datetime2, $datetime1) ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,$datetime2, $datetime1) )";

Please check string concat before run this.

Comment: so this one is already correct? 

$year = $_POST['year'];  
$month = $_POST['month'];  
$day = $_POST['day'];  
$hour = $_POST['hour'];  
$min = $_POST['min'];  
$sec = $_POST['sec'];  
$year1 = $_POST['year1'];  
$month1 = $_POST['month1'];  
$day1 = $_POST['day1'];  
$hour1 = $_POST['hour1'];  
$min1 = $_POST['min1'];  
$sec1 = $_POST['sec1'];  
$time_in = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$hour.'-'.$min.'-'.$sec;  
$time_out = $year1.'-'.$month1.'-'.$day1.' '.$hour1.'-'.$min1.'-'.$sec1;
$total_minutes = $total_min;
$total_hour = $total_hr;

Comment: Yes..Just make change in your time_in / time_out in this format :  2012-01-01   12:00:00;

Comment: or can i ignore the $datetime1 and $datetime2 and make it TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, $time_in, $time_out) ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,$time_in, $time_out)

Comment: format: 2012-01-01 12:00:00 was year-month-day hour:min:sec?

Comment: but the $time_in and $time_out is already at that format so can i ignore the $datetime1 and $datetime2?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO time (year, month, day, hour, min, sec, year1, month1, day1, hour1, min1, sec1, time_in, time_out, total_minutes, total_hour)
  VALUES
  ('$year','$month','$day','$hour','$min','$sec','$year1','$month1','$day1','$hour1','$min1','$sec1','$time_in','$time_out',TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, $datetime2, $datetime1), TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, $datetime2, $datetime1) )
";


i tried this but all row cant insert data in table

Comment: bdw how can i make the total_hour into hh:mm 

TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, $datetime2, $datetime1) 

only gives hour how about the min? like 7:30 it will round off only to 7 when put into database

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL TIMEDIFF() function to get the answer. Instead of PHP, MySQL Function gives the result in very easiest manner.

```
$datetime1 = strtotime($row['time_in']); //year-month-day hr:min:sec timein  
$datetime2 = strtotime($row['time_out']); //year-month-day hr:min:sec timeout  

$timeInterval = mysql_query("SELECT TIMEDIFF($datetime2, $datetime1)");

$timeArray = explode(":", $timeInterval);
```

Hope this may help you :)

Comment: but it doesnt put into the database

Comment: Here we are not inserting into the database. Just we are invoking the function, it simply returns the output. Comparing to PHP, it is a very easiest way to get the difference of time.

Comment: thank you sir but this not the problem. The problem is inserting the difference of time into database.